# js onclick function params

Tags: javascript, html

How can I pass an attribute of div into it's own onclick function?
For example, I have this div:

```
var join_button = document.createElement("div");
join_button.setAttribute("class", "join_button");
join_button.innerHTML = "join";
join_button.setAttribute("room_name", name);
join_button.setAttribute("onclick", "join_room()");
```

Now, in function `join_room()` I need to know the `room name` attribute of this join_button. Ofcourse, I have not only one `join_button` on my page, I dont know it's `names` and I need to handle all of them.

If I try to use `this` It tells me `undefined is not a function`

`function join_room() {
    this.getAttribute("room_name");
}`

`undefined is not a function`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `this` to read the objects attribute.

```
var join_room = function() {
    var room_name = this.getAttribute('room_name);
}
```

then set the onclick like this.

```
join_button.onclick = join_room;
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/LQQz6/1/)

Comment: Yes, I've tryed it, but I have an error on it: undefined is not a function